# Merging pull requests on Github - why not do it locally instead?

Tags: git, github

When I see pull requests on Github with the fancy user interface, I wonder - isn't it better to merge branches locally and then push the results to the Github repo, instead of merging directly on Github? What are the advantages/disadvantages to this?

Answer (score 3):

> What are the advantages/disadvantages to this?

The answer is purely **convenience**.

Some *advantages* to using the GitHub UI to merge pull requests..

- lack of need to use a console.  Maybe you're on the road, and you just review a very basic pull request.  With your phone, you can merge.
- Pull Request-er gets a quick-win when their code is merged in. It doesn't take long to click a button

Some *disadvantages* include..

- lack of ability to control a merge message.  When using the github ui, you get a commit message of : "Merged abc123 into master".  With console, you can opt-out of commit messages using `--no-commit`.
- the inability to sign-off of commits.  Some projects, like [SeleniumHQ/selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium) and [Linux](http://github.com/torvalds/linux) uses a sign-off mechanism built into their workflow *(mostly for legal reasons)*.  You can't do this with the UI.

In fact, some people like Linus [refuse to use the github ui](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/pull/17#issuecomment-5654674) to do pull requests.

Comment: another disadvantage - if the merge fails, and then you mess it up even further, other devs won't be able to pull the latest from the "central"/github remote branch?